# Drupal 7: Display images instead of nodes titles

Tags: php, drupal-7

Normaly in Drupal 7 we have `node.tpl.php`:

```
<?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
    <?php if (!$page): ?>
        <h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>>
            <a href="<?php print $node_url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a>
        </h2>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
```

It is taking `$node_url` and putting it on a Title in every Node.

I do have 5 nodes (pages) displayed:

- First
- Second
- Third etc

I have created images `First.gif`, `Second.gif` and I want to load that images instead of Title.

I did check various implementation, but didn't find any resolution for me.

**[Update]** I did try to edit `template.php` file and to add functions for replacing title with image-if images exists. I need this in Drupal 7 - please see here - http://drupal.org/node/221854

Is there any help? Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Since each node has it's own id then what I'd suggest to you, is to have in your specific `files` folder images such as `node-12`, `node-13` etc.

In your `node.tpl.php`

```php
<?php
// path to our file depending on node id
$file = "path/to/file/node-{$node->nid}.gif";

// check if file exists
if (file_exists($file)) {
    // theme $title as image with theme_image()
    $title = theme('image', array('path' => $file));
}
?>

<h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>>
    <a href="<?php print $node_url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a>
</h2>
```

However I'm sure this is not the best way of development but it work for your question.